# How to use boto3 to send custom EC2 metrics to a CloudWatch Dashboard?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

How to send custom CloudWatch metrics of EC2 instances to a CloudWatch Dashboard using boto3? Custom CloudWatch metrics like : DiskSpaceUsed, PercentFileDescriptorUsed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [put_metric_data](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_data)

I use it extensively to push custom metrics to CloudWatch. Pretty straightforward. Push one metric and check CloudWatch dashboard before pushing other values.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
response = client.put_metric_data(Namespace=..., MetricData=[..])
```

Comment: Thanks. For custom metrics I was sending to CloudWatch Namespace I was giving wrong. I didn't had any issues with regular AWS metrics.